# How can I show overlapping QWidgets with Pyqt5?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a toplevel widget with a layout set and 2 other widgets added to that layout, when I color them all I only see the toplevel widget color but Id like to see the children widgets on top. This is what I have attempted but it just displays a blue QWidget, I am expecting red and green widgets one on top of the other

```
def set_color(widget, color):
    p = widget.palette()
    p.setColor(widget.backgroundRole(), color)
    widget.setPalette(p)

from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget,QVBoxLayout
app = QApplication([])

win = QWidget()
win.show() 
win.resize(1920,1080)

vlayout = QVBoxLayout()
win.setLayout(vlayout)
set_color(win, Qt.blue)

mod_group = QWidget()
mod_layout = QHBoxLayout()
mod_group.setLayout(mod_layout)
vlayout.addWidget(mod_group)
set_color(mod_group, Qt.red)
mod_group.show()

audio_group = QWidget()
audio_layout = QHBoxLayout()
vlayout.addWidget(audio_group)
audio_group.setLayout(audio_layout)
set_color(audio_group, Qt.green)
audio_group.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The widgets are visible but the background color you use is the same as the parent widget, so that they are applied correctly you must enable the [autoFillBackground](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#autoFillBackground-prop) property:

```
mod_group.setAutoFillBackground(True)
audio_group.setAutoFillBackground(True)
```

[image]